# Some form values not getting submitted after using .replaceWith()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

Let's say I have this form:

```
<form action="submit" method="post">
<select name="category" id="categorylist">
<option value="love">Love</option>
<option value="magic">Magic</option>
<option value="custom">Custom</option>
</select>
<textarea name="content">SomeContent</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I wanted to change the `select` into an `input` when I select custom so I came up with this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#categorylist').change(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" name="category">');
  });
  if( $('#categorylist').val() == 'custom' )
    $('#categorylist').replaceWith('<input type="text" name="category">');
});
```

But when the select is changed into an input, `$_POST['category']` isn't there when i dumped `$_POST` on form submission. Why is it so?

Comment: It's better to hard code both elements, select and input, in HTML, with the input initially hidden (using CSS). Then use jQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()` to swap. Whichever element is hidden will not be included in the POST.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yes that works :) Hmm, but I wonder why this doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know. It's not immediately obvious. You could try `.replaceWith('<input type="text" name="category" />')` (in two places). ie. add a closing `/` to the tag. Probably no effect but worth trying.

Comment: I found the problem :) I forgot to mention that I'm using this inside a table, and I found out the form needs to be inside a `<td>`. That solved the problem. It was non-Jquery related. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: <form> does not need to be inside a <td> (though it can be). It is far more usual to see a whole <table> inside a <form>. Whatever you do, make sure the tags balance and are properly nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the `<select>` with `</select>` and `<input type="submit>` to `<input type="submit">` in your html. With following javascript there is no problem with `.replaceWith()` and submitting form.

```
$(function(){
    $('#categorylist').change(function(){
        if( $('#categorylist').val() == 'custom' )
            $('#categorylist').replaceWith('<input type="text" name="category">');
    });
});
```

See [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/jpevn/).

Comment: Have u tested it with PHP? It still ain't submitting.

Comment: With jsfiddle no test with php is available, but in my test I have added an alert which shows, which keys with values will be send. When you copy the script you have to remove the submit-handler to test with your php, because the `return false;` prevents sending the values; this is for the `jsfiddle`-test only.